# add multiple xml elements value into a list

Tags: xml, linq

The following code works but I would like to accomplish the same result, which is insert the distinct values of elements "triptype" and "description" into a list, with one single query. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Marcelo

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<Trips>
                      <Trip>
                        <triptype>vacation</triptype>
                        <description>Trip to Bahamas</description>
                        <id>89</id>
                      </Trip>
                      <Trip>
                        <triptype>vacation</triptype>
                        <description>Trip to California</description>
                        <id>75</id>
                      </Trip>
                      <Trip>
                        <triptype>business</triptype>
                        <description>Trip to Chicago</description>
                        <id>82</id>
                      </Trip>
                    </Trips>";

        List<string> trips = new List<string>();

        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var tripTypes = (from t in xdoc.Descendants("Trip")
                             .Elements("triptype")
                      select t.Value).Distinct();

        foreach (var tripType in tripTypes)
        {
            trips.Add(tripType);
        }

        var tripDescriptions = (from t in xdoc.Descendants("Trip")
                                    .Elements("description") 
                                select t.Value).Distinct();

        foreach (var tripDescription in tripDescriptions)
        {
            trips.Add(tripDescription);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no way to select multiple elements with a single LINQ to XML query as you're trying to achieve with distinct values.

However, you could project the sequence into an anonymous type with each element's value and then find the distinct values, but I suspect that would probably be overkill and harder to understand than what you're doing now, i.e.,

```
var query = xdoc.Root.Elements( "Trip" )
        .Select( x => new
                      {
                              trip = x.Element( "triptype" ).Value,
                              desc = x.Element( "description" ).Value
                      } ).ToList();

trips.AddRange( query.Select( x => x.trip ).Union( query.Select( x => x.desc ) ).Distinct() );
```

Rather, I would suggest a slight clean-up by using [List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a `foreach` loop and use the same logic as you're using now by getting each distinct set of values for each node needed:

```
var q1 = xdoc.Descendants( "triptype" ).Select( x => x.Value ).Distinct();
var q2 = xdoc.Descendants( "description" ).Select( x => x.Value ).Distinct();
trips.AddRange( q1.Union( q2 ) );
```

Comment: Great! You are right, using List.AddRange is a much cleaner solution. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!